# Can we add swashbuckle as middleware to Azure function app (out of process)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-functions

I have the below-mentioned code to configure for the Function App. I am trying to set up Swagger for the function app APIs.I need some guidance on how I can enable Swagger middleware with the below code for the function app.

**Sample Code-**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker => {
        worker.UseNewtonsoftJson();
        worker.UseMiddleware<AuthorizationMiddleware>();


    }).ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddLocalClients();
          
        services.AddWorkerServices();
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options => {
            options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description =
                    "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n " +
                    "Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\n" +
                    "Example: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Scheme = "Bearer"
            });
            options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            },
                Scheme = "oauth2",
                Name = "Bearer",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
            },
            new List<string>()
        }
    });
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1.0",
                Title = "Sample V1",
                Description = "API to manage XXXXX",
                TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
                Contact = new OpenApiContact
                {
                    Name = "xxxxxx",
                    Url = new Uri("https://example.com")
                },
                License = new OpenApiLicense
                {
                    Name = "Example License",
                    Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license")
                }
            });
            
        });
    }).ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
    {

        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
    })     
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    })
    .Build();
host.Run();
```

I am using .NET 7 and Azure function V4. I would like to know where I can enable the middleware like we can do in web API as below-
On the web, I can see examples of web API where IApplicationBuilder is used to enable middleware.
IApplicationBuilder is generally used in in-process function apps or web applications.Since, I amusing isolated version, how can I enable swagger middleware?
One way I am thinking is to implement extending IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware as I did for Authorization. Will that work?

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "XXXXXX");
            
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [doc](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/general-availability-of-azure-functions-openapi-extension/ba-p/2931231) OpenAPI Extension is possible in `.NET 6` both `In-Process` and `Out-of-Process` Worker.

Thanks @Justin Yoo for the clear steps.

I have followed the same for .NET 7.

- Create an Azure Function `.NET 7`.
  [image]
- Install the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi` NuGet packages.

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.10.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

- In `program.cs` file, change `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()`   as below

```cs
 .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker => worker.UseNewtonsoftJson())
 .ConfigureOpenApi()
```

- In the `Function1.cs` file add the below decorators to the Function. With this the function app will recognize this endpoint and it gets included in the openapi.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Enums;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

  [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "Run", tags: new[] { "greetings" })]
  [OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
  [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "text/plain", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The OK response")]
```

- Build and run the Application.
- Now the output looks as below.4 more URL's get added to the Output.

[image]

- Run the `RenderSwaggerUI` Endpoint.

[image]

> One way I am thinking is to implement extending IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware as I did for Authorization. Will that work?

Yes,even implementing `IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware`  will also work.

### Update

Check the below code to work only in the Development and Staging Environment.

- Get the environment name and call `ConfigureOpenApi` only in the `Development`/`Staging` environment.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT");

var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker =>
    {
        worker.UseNewtonsoftJson();
    });  


if (env == EnvironmentName.Development || env == EnvironmentName.Staging)
{
    hostBuilder.ConfigureOpenApi();
}

var host = hostBuilder.Build();
host.Run();
```

Comment: The above configuration will work. But, I want it to run in DEV and Test and not in the PROD environment. So was thinking of something we can handle in middleware.

Comment: The example which I shared is in Dev Environment.

Comment: Where Can I add a check for that, so that it does not run in PROD?
ConfigureOpenApi() will add it in PROD as well.

Comment: Will check and let you know.

Comment: Please check the Update section in the Posted answer.

Comment: I have one question. How are we going to authenticate the user when it tries to load Swagger UI in the browser? As we are not using swagger implementation like Swashbuckle. How to configure user authentication?  The Function App is  Azure AD  protected.

Comment: @suraj_123 you have to manually validate the request. If the Bearer token provided, then first check the header is present, then extract the token and validate it. I don't know any other built-in authentication exists in the Function app.